# Summing with a for loop faster than with reduce?

Tags: python, performance

I wanted to see how much faster reduce was than using a for loop for simple numerical operations. Here's what I found (using the standard timeit library):

```
In [54]: print(setup)
from operator import add, iadd
r = range(100)

In [55]: print(stmt1)    
c = 0
for i in r:
    c+=i        

In [56]: timeit(stmt1, setup)
Out[56]: 8.948904991149902
In [58]: print(stmt3)    
reduce(add, r)    

In [59]: timeit(stmt3, setup)
Out[59]: 13.316915035247803
```

Looking a little more:

```
In [68]: timeit("1+2", setup)
Out[68]: 0.04145693778991699

In [69]: timeit("add(1,2)", setup)
Out[69]: 0.22807812690734863
```

What's going on here? Obviously, reduce does loop faster than for, but the function call seems to dominate. Shouldn't the reduce version run almost entirely in C? Using iadd(c,i) in the for loop version makes it run in ~24 seconds. Why would using operator.add be so much slower than +? I was under the impression + and operator.add run the same C code (I checked to make sure operator.add wasn't just calling + in python or anything).

BTW, just using sum runs in ~2.3 seconds.

```
In [70]: print(sys.version)
2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 09:39:13) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5494)]
```

Comment: The fact that using `sum` does the job 4 times faster is pretty much an indicator that "there should be one obvious way to do it".

Comment: @jsbbueno: True, but I was doing this to figure out the fastest way of doing general numeric calculations over sequences. In the real world, I would certainly use sum to sum :D Haven't tried mul, but I'm sure the results would be similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `reduce(add, r)` must invoke the `add()` function 100 times, so the overhead of the function calls adds up -- reduce uses `PyEval_CallObject` to invoke `add` on each iteration:

```
for (;;) {
    ...
    if (result == NULL)
        result = op2;
    else {
        # here it is creating a tuple to pass the previous result and the next
        # value from range(100) into func add():
        PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, result);
        PyTuple_SetItem(args, 1, op2);
        if ((result = PyEval_CallObject(func, args)) == NULL)
            goto Fail;
    }
```

**Updated**: Response to question in comments.

When you type `1 + 2` in Python source code, the bytecode compiler performs the addition in place and replaces that expression with `3`:

```
f1 = lambda: 1 + 2
c1 = byteplay.Code.from_code(f1.func_code)
print c1.code

1           1 LOAD_CONST           3
            2 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you add two variables `a + b` the compiler will generate bytecode which loads the two variables and performs a BINARY_ADD, which is far faster than calling a function to perform the addition:

```
f2 = lambda a, b: a + b
c2 = byteplay.Code.from_code(f2.func_code)
print c2.code

1           1 LOAD_FAST            a
            2 LOAD_FAST            b
            3 BINARY_ADD           
            4 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! However, it doesn't explain why the raw '1+2' is 5x faster than 'add(1,2)'. Indeed, the reduce is much faster than the for when using iadd in the for.

Comment: Why do your examples use a third-party package instead of the built-in `dis` module?

Comment: No particular reason except I happen to be using it at the moment.

Comment: instead of `byteplay.Code.from_code(f1.func_code)` you could use `dis.dis(f1)` if you don't have `biteplay`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the overhead of copying args and return values (i.e. "add(1, 2)"), opposed to simply operating on numeric literals

Answer (score 0):

*edit*: Switching out zeroes instead of array multiply closes the gap big time.

```
from functools import reduce
from numpy import array, arange, zeros
from time import time

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def sum_columns(x):
    if x.any():
        width = len(x[0])
        total = zeros(width)
    for row in x:
        total += array(row)
    return total

l = arange(3000000)
l = array([l, l, l])

start = time()
print(reduce(add, l))
print('Reduce took {}'.format(time() - start))

start = time()
print(sum_columns(l))
print('For loop took took {}'.format(time() - start))
```

Gets you down almost no difference at all.

`Reduce took 0.03230619430541992
For loop took took 0.058577775955200195`

*old*: If reduce is used for adding together NumPy arrays by index, it can be faster than a for loop.

```
from functools import reduce
from numpy import array, arange
from time import time

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def sum_columns(x):
    if x.any():
        width = len(x[0])
        total = array([0] * width)
    for row in x:
        total += array(row)
    return total

l = arange(3000000)
l = array([l, l, l])

start = time()
print(reduce(add, l))
print('Reduce took {}'.format(time() - start))

start = time()
print(sum_columns(l))
print('For loop took took {}'.format(time() - start))
```

With the result of

```
[      0       3       6 ..., 8999991 8999994 8999997]
Reduce took 0.024930953979492188
[      0       3       6 ..., 8999991 8999994 8999997]
For loop took took 0.3731539249420166
```

Comment: there are several reasons why the for-loop is so horrendously slow in this example. 1) Use `zeros` instead of creating the zero array with `array([0] * width)`. 2) there are very few elements in `l` array which favours the reduce function because the `for` loop overhead is to high. The for-loop _is_ faster once you have 6 or more elements.

Comment: @zeroth it does indeed narrow the gap pretty massively. They're almost identical in perf with python 3.6 and the latest version of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was curious, here are some more up-to-date tests on 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04.

With python 3.8.10, reduce is actually faster for this simple loop:

```bash
$ python3 -m pyperf timeit -s 'c=0' 'for i in range(10000):c+=i'
Mean +- std dev: 410 us +- 20 us

$ python3 -m pyperf timeit -s 'from functools import reduce; from operator import add' 'reduce(add, range(10000))'
Mean +- std dev: 317 us +- 11 us
```

For doing fewer multiplications, the for loop is still faster:

```bash
$ python3 -m pyperf timeit -s 'c=0' 'for i in range(1,100):c*=i'
Mean +- std dev: 3.00 us +- 0.39 us

$ python3 -m pyperf timeit -s 'from functools import reduce; from operator import mul' 'reduce(mul, range(1,100))'
Mean +- std dev: 4.39 us +- 0.22 us
```

Of course, for any number crunching I would use PyPy or numpy. Here are the results for PyPy 7.3.12 (assuming pyperf accounts for JIT startup time accurately):

```bash
$ pypy3 -m pyperf timeit -s 'c=0' 'for i in range(10000):c+=i'
Mean +- std dev: 10.1 us +- 0.9 us

$ pypy3 -m pyperf timeit -s 'from functools import reduce; from operator import add' 'reduce(add, range(10000))'
Mean +- std dev: 14.7 us +- 1.0 us

$ pypy3 -m pyperf timeit -s 'c=0' 'for i in range(1,100):c*=i'
Mean +- std dev: 141 ns +- 26 ns

$ pypy3 -m pyperf timeit -s 'from functools import reduce; from operator import mul' 'reduce(mul, range(1,100))'
Mean +- std dev: 1.95 us +- 0.06 us
```

For addition, the for-loop is about 30% faster, but for multiplication it's almost 14x faster. So PyPy clearly optimizes the commonly used for-loop more.

All the functional `map` and `reduce` so far are using python's built-in single-core functions. It is trivial for a library to parallelize map and reduce (over pure functions at least), so that's where the real power of map comes in.