# How to reformat variables in lists in list to make one list

Tags: python, list, combinations

Very popular answer but my one differs from others.
I have a list:

```
s = [(1, 2, 3),
     (4, 5, 6),
     (7, 8, 9)]
```

I need without another lists combine my lists inside and make one big list.
I need them to be string so I do

```
[map(str, x) for x in s]
```

But in this way I get `[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]`

So I need `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need list comprehension with flatenning:

```
print ([i for x in s for i in map(str, x)])
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
s = [(1, 2, 3),
    (4, 5, 6),
    (7, 8, 9)]
print(list(map(str,itertools.chain(*s))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` and `list`:

```
map(str, list(sum(s, ())))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using a nestled list comprehension is perhaps the easiest

```
>>> [str(sii) for si in s for sii in si]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to make the flat list and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to cast elements to string.

```
>>> from functools import reduce

>>> s = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6),(7, 8, 9)]
>>> list(map(str,reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,s)))
>>> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: Tho concise, I find `reduce` a lot slower than most other more "verbose" ways in Python. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @CalvinKu [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5436709/5741172) :)

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.chain` is convenient for this purpose:

```
from itertools import chain

s = [(1, 2, 3),
     (4, 5, 6),
     (7, 8, 9)]

list(map(str, chain.from_iterable(s)))

# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```